# Asp.net site failing only in new IE version

Tags: asp.net, iis, internet-explorer-11

I have a site in asp.net (Req. of the client, is actually an old code they had)
It is in IIS. It works in Chrome, Firefox, IE 10 and IE 11 version 11.0.9600.17690 but not working in IE version 11.0.9600.17691

In this version, the site is refreshing over and over and it doesnt load what it should be loading.

The HTML is formed like this

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,chrome=1" />
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

I tried with IE edge too.

Is there a new configuration that i migth be missing?

If I run the site from VisualStudio directly or from firefox, chrome or other IE version, it works fine.

Comment: Refreshing could be a lot of things.  Cookies not being turned on and wreaking havoc with session, url rewrites not rewriting properly, or IE being in compatibility mode.  I'd check that IE is allowing cookies AND is (or isn't) in compatibility mode first - if it works on all other browsers, then it's most likely that the problem lies with the browser.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have a similar issue where my website doesn't load in Edge (or IE on WP8) that I can't get to the bottom of.